# MacOS: how to avoid ssl hell on intel mac with Raku?

Tags: macos, ssl, openssl, raku

Been having major problems today trying to get https://github.com/finanalyst/raku-pod-render installed.

One of the big problems is tests failing that use ssl encryption. See:

https://github.com/grondilu/libdigest-raku/issues/25

https://github.com/jnthn/p6-io-socket-async-ssl/issues/69

And then there's this older issue I submitted back in March:
https://github.com/jnthn/p6-ssh-libssh/issues/18

So that's three different modules so far I've had trouble installing on the mac. I've got openssl@1.1 and openssl@3 brew packages installed on my machine.

Any suggestions from other mac users for how I might get this straightened out for good?

Comment: Are you aware of [CAVEATS](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/CAVEATS.md#dynamic-libraries) ?

Comment: No. Interesting. I'll check it out.

Comment: I don't think it really needs it. Seem to remember there was an issue raised. Why would a Pod rendering library need SSL?

Comment: Anything that needs to open a arbitrary URL needs SSL, so it's very easy for any deps to pull in this requirement.

Comment: Are you subscribed to the mailing list? https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl6.users/2022/06/msg10567.html

Comment: There have been a few tickets opened here for raku/ssl/macos problems: https://github.com/jnthn/p6-io-socket-async-ssl/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+macos

Comment: @jjmerelo MacOS issue with SSL and Raku's LWP-Simple community module:  https://github.com/raku-community-modules/LWP-Simple.

Answer (score 0):

While I love macOS for many reasons, I think that it has wondered off the "true north" it used to point for *nix development.

This is true for Intel CPUs and even more so for ARM M CPUs.

So I [recommend](https://p6steve.wordpress.com/2021/11/27/raku-at-monterey-docks-part-ii/) Docker on ubuntu on vftools on mac:

https://medium.com/carvago-development/my-docker-on-macos-part-1-setup-ubuntu-virtual-machine-both-intel-and-apple-silicon-cpu-5d886af0ebba

So now I can start my ubuntu-vm with docker in the morning and reach for something like:

```
docker pull --platform linux/arm64 rakudo-star

docker run -it --entrypoint sh -l -c rakudo-star

raku
```

Comment: I think the problem is just a lot of hard core developers doing low level stuff are going to be using Linux, not macs.

Comment: yep - so my solution is to just run ubuntu in a vftools vm on my mac YMMV

Comment: However, most people expect a programming language to be cross-platform out of the box. Some effort should be placed into making it so.